# How to approximate the function of a curve given a table of values?

Tags: calculus, arithmetic

Let $w$ be the angle given by the function $cos^{-1}(x)$. Therefore, $w=cos^{-1}(x)$.

Let $y$ be the height given by the function $sin(w)$. Therefore, $y=sin(w)$.

let $r$ be the radius of the circle with the value of 1. Therefore, $r=1$.

Starting from $x=0$, as you increase the value of x, then both, the value of w (the angle) and the value of y (the height) will decrease respectively. When you follow the trajectory of the graph, you will notice that the arc of a circle is being drawn downwards.

Now my question is, if the function of sine and cosine did not exist and all you have is a precalculated table of approximated values that represent some of the pair of xy coordinates that the graph happens to go through. In other words, this table represent the approximated or partial trajectory of the arc. Then, how can you apply a method of approximation to generate a function that approximates this trajectory using the data sample from a table?

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| $\frac{0}{6}$ | r |
| $\frac{1}{6}$ | 0.9868 |
| $\frac{2}{6}$ | 0.9428 |
| $\frac{3}{6}$ | 0.8660 |
| $\frac{4}{6}$ | 0.7454 |
| $\frac{5}{6}$ | 0.5528 |
| $\frac{6}{6}$ | 0 |

Comment: Linear interpolation is the first idea. Joining your point by line segments, means algebraicaly that, on each interval $[x_k,x_{k+1}]$, you have to find an equation $y=ax+b$ with $y_k=ax_k+b$ and $y_{k+1}=ax_{k+1}+b$ (a system of two linear equations with 2 unknowns $a$ and $b$).

Comment: The simplest idea is simply to use the $y$ value of nearest known $x$ to your input. This gives a "step function" which is visually poor, but sometimes sufficient numerically. Next is linear interpolation as Jean Marie describes. If that still isn't sufficient, then [cubic splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) is usually the next step up. There is seldom much to be gained by going any higher than that, unless you have additional information about the function than just its values at a list of points.